# Integrate SymPy Array

Tags: sympy

Not sure where is the best place to ask this question. I am trying to integrate a SymPy Array, but if

```
sympy.integrate(x, (x, 0, 1))
```

returns

```
1/2
```

as expected,

```
sympy.integrate(sympy.Array([x]), (x, 0, 1))
```

returns

```
1
```

which is quite troubling. Any hint? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the docstring suggest that you should be able to integrate Array? Does any test in the integrals tests folder involve Array? That's a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks! Quite frankly I don't know. I did not find anything suggesting it would not work, so I gave it a try, but indeed it does not seem to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume `Array` is a bit finicky with calculus operations since it seems that inherits from tensors. You would have to do some digging to find out why. The `Matrix` class however tends to do a little better. When I was doing a bit of vector calculus, I found that using `Matrix` helped a lot.

For your question we have:

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
print(integrate(Matrix([[x]]), (x, 0, 1)))
```

Which produces as expected:

```py
Matrix([[1/2]])
```

It also works for larger matrices:

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
A = Matrix([[x],
            [x+1],
            [x**2]])  # column vector
print(integrate(A, x))

B = Matrix([[1, x, x**2],
            [-x, 2, 0],
            [sin(x), cos(x), tan(x)]])
print(integrate(B, x))
```

Producing:

```py
Matrix([[x**2/2], [x**2/2 + x], [x**3/3]])
Matrix([[x, x**2/2, x**3/3], [-x**2/2, 2*x, 0], [-cos(x), sin(x), -log(cos(x))]])
```

If you really need to integrate tensors, then that math is far out of my range but it seems you can at least [differentiate them](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html#functions).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I am indeed working with nd arrays. Current workflow is to integrate term-by-term. Thanks again anyway.